# Is there a way to reduce duplication here?

Tags: ocaml

I am creating a prisoner's dilemma simulation and I have two functions that are counting cooperations and defections done by the two players and outputting them as a tuple. I see a lot of similarities and would like some guidance on how to consolidate the two functions into another function that the two can call upon so I am not reusing code. I am very new in OCaml so I am struggling to find a way to do this!

Here is the necessary information:

```
type action = bool ;;
type play = action * action ;;
type history = play list 

let rec count_defections (history : history) : (int * int) = 
  match history with
  | [] -> (0, 0)
  | play :: rest ->
    match play with
    | (player1, player2) ->
      match count_defections rest with
      | (d1, d2) ->
        if (player1, player2) = (false, false) then (d1 + 1, d2 + 1)
        else if (player1, player2) = (false, true) then (d1 + 1, d2)
        else if (player1, player2) = (true, false) then (d1, d2 + 1)
        else (d1, d2) ;;

let rec count_cooperations (history : history) : (int * int) = 
  match history with
  | [] -> (0, 0)
  | play :: rest ->
    match play with
    | (player1, player2) ->
      match count_cooperations rest with
      | (d1, d2) ->
        if (player1, player2) = (true, true) then (d1 + 1, d2 + 1)
        else if (player1, player2) = (true, false) then (d1 + 1, d2)
        else if (player1, player2) = (false, true) then (d1, d2 + 1)
        else (d1, d2) ;;
```

My first thoughts were:

```
let count_common (history : history) : (int * int) =
  match history with
  | [] -> (0, 0)
  | play :: rest ->
    match play with
    | (player1, player2) ->
      match .....
```

But I don't really understand  how to do the rest.

Comment: note that instead of wrting `match count_defections rest with | (d1, d2) -> ...` , you can write `let (d1,d2) = count_defections rest in ...`. Also you can pattern match deeply over `play` to avoid the double match as in: `match history with  | [] -> (0, 0)  | (player1,player2):: rest -> ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that counts the two parts of a pair separately, counting elements that equal a given value.

```
let count_val_in_pairs value pairs =
    List.fold_left
        (fun (cta, ctb) (a, b) ->
            ((if a = value then cta + 1 else cta),
             (if b = value then ctb + 1 else ctb)))
        (0, 0)
        pairs
```

Your `count_defections` is this:

```
let count_defections history =
    count_val_in_pairs false history
```

Your `count_cooperations` is this:

```
let count_cooperations history =
    count_val_in_pairs true history
```